# get_terms function to return all child categories not returning all results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a given category's child categories like so:

```
$this->getChildCategories = function($parent_id) {                          

        $args = array(
            'parent'         => $parent_id,                 
        ); 

        $terms = get_terms('category', $args);

        return $terms;

};
```

When having a look in the dashboard, there are 10 child categories in total. However the function only returns 5 results.

Comment: maybe other five have no posts try `hide_empty=>false,` to get terms

Comment: @ShravanShrama that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling the function in a wrong way. If you refer the function in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children), here's how it is called:

```
get_term_children( $term, $taxonomy );
```

So to get the children categories of a category, here's what we gotta do:

```
get_term_children( $term, $taxonomy  ); //where $term is "category_id" and $taxonomy is "category"
```

Since you have slug not the id of the parent category, you can obtain the id by this [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug):

```
$parent_category = get_category_by_slug('category-slug'); 
$parent_category_id = $parent_category->term_id;
```

Using the above functions to write our own function to get the children categories:

```
function get_children_categories($category_slug, $taxonomy_name){
   $parent_category = get_category_by_slug($category_slug); 
   $parent_category_id = $parent_category->term_id;
   //$Uncategorized_id = get_cat_ID('Uncategorized') ;
   $children_categories = get_term_children( $parent_category_id, $taxonomy_name);
   //unset($children_categories[$Uncategorized_id]);
  return $children_categories;
}
```

The above functions also returns "uncategorized", so to remove that you can uncomment the commented part in the above function.

You can call the function get_children_categories by passing the parameters:

```
get_children_categories('event', 'category') //shall return all the children category ids.
```

Now you have all the children category ids of the category passed. To get the term object, you can use the following function:

```
get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter )
```

Thank.

P.s: I had to personally search you since you deleted your last question. This however is the answer to your last question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable default limitation:

```
'numberposts' => -1,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parent category ID instead of `$cat->cat_ID.`

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```